# Como referenciar elementos HTML sem ID no C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, html

Boa noite!

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<H3>Dados Cadastrais</H3>
  <table class='dados'>
  <tr>
    <th>Avalista:</th>
    <td>VINICIUS ALVES GONZALEZ</td>
    <th>Contrato:</th>
    <td>72001018  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
```

Como posso referenciar este elemento usando C# para pegar o nome do cliente dentro do `<td>` e o numero do contrato tbm ...

Consigo somente com items que possuem ID usando o `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 2):

Você já tentou utilizar o [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp)

> Install-Package AngleSharp

```
var xml = @"
<H3>Dados Cadastrais</H3>
<table class='dados'>
<tr>
    <th>Avalista:</th>
    <td>VINICIUS ALVES GONZALEZ</td>
    <th>Contrato:</th>
    <td>72001018  </td>
</tr>";


var parser = new HtmlParser();
var document = parser.Parse(xml);

Console.WriteLine(document.QuerySelector("td:nth-child(2)").InnerHtml);
Console.WriteLine(document.QuerySelector("td:nth-child(4)").InnerHtml);
```

resultado:

```
VINICIUS ALVES GONZALEZ
72001018
```

Answer (score 0):

Você quiser dizer pegar os elementos DOM utilizando `JavaScript` para depois mandar esses dados para `C#`?

Você pode utilizar além do `document.getElementById()`, o `document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0]` *note que o índice [0] é por que no seu caso retornaria os dois `td`'s*.

Tem também o `document.getElementsByClassName("nome")` *note que para este funcionar, você teria que em seu `html` alterar o campo **td** onde está o nome para `<td class="nome">VINICIUS ALVES GONZALEZ</td>`*.

Você ainda pode pegar elementos pelos values e por qualquer outro atributo que quiser, só que você precisará de uma função mais complexa para isso. Esta função primeiro irá pegar todos os elementos e verificar em todos se existe o atributo que você deseja e se o valor desse atributo seja o mesmo que você deseja.

Comment: No caso, o cod HTML não é meu, é de uma page na net onde eu preciso pegar estes valores... Então no caso para que eu consiga pegar o "td" com o nome eu devo localizar dentro do "[0]" que varia, o valor?

Comment: Sim, será um grande desafio pra você identificar que isso seja o nome e não outro dado, uma vez que as tags estão sem identificadores.
Imagine que essa page utilize mais de uma tabela, logo seu `document.getElementsByTagName("td")` iria retornar todos os `td` da página inteira.
Dai nesse caso, a solução seria conseguir pegar um elemento dentro de outro que já está identificado.
Percebi que a tabela que contém esses dados têm uma classe dados. Logo seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim. `document.getElementsByClass("dados")[0].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];`